# Free, basic checkbox images for a todo list

Tags: images, website-design, icon

Does anyone have a set of simple, free checkbox images (checked and unchecked)?  I've got to throw a todo list on my site and I'm not exactly a designer.  Ones that look like they are hand written would be great.

Comment: In addition to images, you might consider using iconic web fonts (like Webdings, but better), for example: http://pictos.cc/ (demo at http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/ )

Comment: Had to end up drawing my own set in GIMP.  Kind of surprised this got closed, as this is a simple, answerable question.

Comment: Here's what I came up with, use them if you like: http://s1251.photobucket.com/albums/hh544/kochb/

Answer (score 3):

You could just use these Unicode characters:

- ☐ [U+2610, Ballot box](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2610/)
- ☑ [U+2611, Ballot box with check](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2611/)
- ☒ [U+2612, Ballot box with X](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2612/)

See, no images needed!

Comment: I love Unicode characters -- just be aware that IE7 and maybe even IE8 won't render them (at least, properly) -- and Windows in general has some issues displaying a lot of Unicode characters (I'm on a Mac so I can't tell from here with those you've suggested). So this is a great solution; just do some testing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [search engine query](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=free+vector+checklist+icon&pbx=1&oq=free+vector+checklist+icon&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=66l826l1l1456l5l5l0l0l0l0l45l173l5l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=e7854375dd047176&biw=1919&bih=1079), there are hundreds of design sites out there that offer this stuff. Generally google 'free vector [type of graphic]' and you'll find what you're looking for, be it vector or raster.